# return json data split up into different values Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift4, codable

Currently we have json values returning in this format

```
 "CSS_RGB__c": "rgb(190,102,123)",
```

I'm trying to spit the values into indivual ,r,g,b values (ex. r = 190, g = 102, b = 123)

previously this worked:

```
if let raw = dictionary["CSS_RGB__c"] as? NSString {
    let filtered = raw.substring(from: 4).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ")"))
    var values = filtered.components(separatedBy: ",")
    if values.count == 3 {
        self["r"] = NSString(string: values[0]).floatValue as NSNumber?
        self["g"] = NSString(string: values[1]).floatValue as NSNumber?
        self["b"] = NSString(string: values[2]).floatValue as NSNumber?
    }
}
```

but with the new way swift 4 parses json I'm not entirely sure how to split up the values:

```
struct Family: Codable {
 let cssRGBC: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
   case cssRGBC = "CSS_RGB__c"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find a string between two strings, map its range to extract the result, use `components(separatedBy: ",")` to get the rgb components and initialize a new integer from the strings trimming the white spaces if present:

```
let raw = "rgb(190,102,123)"
let regexPattern = "(?<=rgb\\()(.*)(?=\\))"
if let rgb = raw.range(of: regexPattern, options: .regularExpression)
    .map({String(raw[$0])})?
    .components(separatedBy: ",")
    .flatMap({Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))}){
    print(rgb)  // "[190, 102, 123]\n"
}
```

Comment: This is good, what if I need the values of r,g,b separately, like r = 190, g = 102 etc

Comment: `rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]`